# Launch process in new window, whether GNU screen session exists or not

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, window

I'm having a bit of trouble with GNU's *screen*.  What I want to do is this (from `cron`):

If a screen session named *cron* exists, add a new window to the session and launch a process in it (but do not attach to the session).  Otherwise, create a new session called *cron* and launch the process in it (again, do not attach).  If possible, all of this should be done using just one "screen" command.

I've already tried a bit but haven't come to a solution that satisfies all of my needs:

```
screen -S cron -dRRm screen ping example.com
screen -S cron -X screen ping example.com
```

Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this in one command, but this should do what you want:

```
screen -ls cron | grep -q '(\w*tached)' >&- || screen -dmS cron
screen -S cron -X screen ping example.com
```